# CSS Positioning on header

Tags: css, html-helper

Trying to mess with this store theme and can't figure out why the header picture is not positioning in center block. Any help would be very appreciated. http://www.bijuteriionline.eu/products/Inel-Logodna-cu-Ametist.html

Comment: what is your problem and what should we answer you??

Answer (score 0):

add to your #Logo the following line:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: its about the Flat Rate Shipping Banner

Answer (score 0):

add to your `.topbanner-wrapper` class

```
width:1000px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

**EDIT** 
forgot one more line:

also add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```